# HTML, why browser loading files slow

Tags: html, web, server

I was trying to monitoring a test website by Firefox, I notice that it takes a while to download js and css file. Compare to other website like microsoft or apple, even their file size is bigger, but they loaded very fast.

[image: Fire Fox screenshot]

Customer host the website on their own server. Is it because server's configuration is lower?
This is screenshot of server's environment:

[image]

Customer is complaining the page load slowly. The also have couple big size images on their website. The page's structure is not very complicate. I basically import couple of js, css file and put couple of images on for test only.

So server really matters？

thanks in advance

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons this could occur:

- Upload speed of the internet connection the server has that is hosting the site.
- Download speed of the internet connection the browser is on.

However I would recommend using as many CDN's that you can to reduce the actual load on the server hosting the site.

jQuery and Bootstrap are available via CDN's.